# Accessing Keyword metadata in a custom Storage extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, storage-extensions

I'm developing a custom Storage extension to publish Tridion 2013 SP1 items into a NoSQL database but I'm struggling to find a way to gain access to the metadata on a Keyword when a user publishes a Category.

I know you can extend the `JPATaxonomyDAO` class and within the `store` method you are given a `TaxonomyItem` object where you can get access to the `Description` and the `Name` of a Keyword, but is there anyway to get access to the metadata?

I assume they must be in there somewhere as the metadata eventually goes into the the `Custom_Meta` Broker database table?

Andrew Whitehead's useful [code](https://github.com/ajwhitehead88/tridion-couchbase-delivery/blob/master/src/storage_module/src/com/tridion/storage/extensions/couchbase/JPACouchbaseTaxonomyDAO.java) got me so far but doesn't extract the metadata.

Comment: Did you got any way to extract the metadata? I'm having the same requirement.

Comment: No I didn't. It seems it is not possible

Comment: I think you need extend the `JPAItemDAO` class as well. This should also have a store method. With the `ItemMeta` object passed to this method, you'll be able to enrich the document that  you've already stored in your NoSQL database.

I've managed to do this after some input from a client. As a hint my `cd_storage_conf.xml` includes the following item type:

`<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="couchbase" />`